# Are there any known muggle-born wizards/witches who have a magical sibling?

Tags: harry-potter

We know of at least one Muggle-born magic user who had a sibling (Lily Evans) - and her sister was a Muggle.

Did JKR books contain at least one case of Muggle-born siblings BOTH of whom were wizards/witches?

(100% Muggle-born; half-bloods don't count)

Comment: This is related to [another Q](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46453/is-the-magical-power-skill-difference-typical-among-siblings-in-potterverse) I asked, since I am researching heritability of magic in Potterverse.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Colin Creevey... and his brother Dennis.

In the Chamber of Secrets Colin unabashedly shares his Muggle-bornness:

> It’s amazing here, isn’t it? I never knew all the odd stuff I could do was magic till I got the letter from Hogwarts. My dad’s a milkman, he couldn’t believe it either. So I’m taking loads of pictures to send home to him.

Dennis is introduced in The Goblet of Fire:

> It was Colin Creevey, a third year to whom Harry was something of a hero.
>   “Hi, Colin,” said Harry warily.
>   “Harry, guess what? Guess what, Harry? My brother’s starting! My brother Dennis!”
>   “Er – good," said Harry.

From [HP Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Colin_Creevey):

> Colin Creevey grew up in an ordinary Muggle family. He was the son of a milkman and was amazed to find out he was a wizard attending Hogwarts. Colin was continually awestruck at everything to do with the wizarding world. Colin had a younger brother named Dennis, who was also a wizard, an unusual thing to occur for two magical offspring to come from Muggle parents.

Comment: Oh! I forgot they were muggle-born! Drop in a quote showing the muggle-bornness and I'll accept!

Comment: @DVK on the very first page we meet him, in Chamber ch. 6, Colin says “I never knew all the odd stuff I could do was magic till I got the letter from Hogwarts. My dad's a milkman, he couldn't believe it either.”